# Having multiple main classes in a Java project?

Tags: java

Suppose that I have a Java code base and I want to be able to execute multiple tasks that are based on this same base:

1. Run an embedded Jetty web server.
2. Run a one-time initialization of database (creation, seed, etc.)
3. Run a cron-scheduled maintenance operation (cleanup, backup, etc.)
4. Maybe more ...

I was thinking about building multiple standalone Jars, each compiled with the same base, but with different main entry points. I think it would work, but just felt a bit redundant. Those Jars basically contain the same things, if not because of the different main classes.

I'm not familiar with Java. Is there a standard way of doing these things in Java? What do you think about the approach that I mentioned above?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to run multiple applications?

Why can't you just run additional threads.  You can have a background thread run for your initialization to your Database, and you can run a background thread whenever you need to do scheduled maintenance, and other things.  

JavaFX has the "Task" class that allows you to run tasks in additional threads.

Running multiple applications/jars doesn't make much sense to me, but maybe I'm not fully sure what you're doing.

Comment: Growing up with scripting language, I got accustomed to have different scripts to handle different tasks. For example, in Ruby on Rails, we have the command `rails server` to start a web server, `rails console` to start an interactive Ruby console, `rake db:migrate` to do database migration, and so on.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with scripting languages, but are they running together, or are they all separate.  I would say each script could be like a class, or part of an application that runs.  If everything runs together, there is no point, imo, to have them run as separate applications/jars.  You would do that when you have 2 completely different applications, and you might need to do something between the 2 of them, or maybe some other situation, but your situation just sounds like "I sometimes want to run this or that within my application" which is what threads are for, imo.

Comment: In scripting language like Ruby, they will typically run in separate processes. For example, without stopping a running web server, I can SSH to the server and execute a script to do a maintenance/administrative operation. I agree that using a thread is probably a more resource-efficient way to achieve what I want to do, but at the expense of having to implement my own way to trigger this thread (calling a secret, password-protected URL to the web server?). Thanks for reference to the notion of Task in JavaFX, I will take a look at it!

Comment: You can do separate processes as well, but those seem to be if you are running multiple things concurrently in the background, but these are more task oriented and probably better for a background thread to run individually.  The thread would be triggered in your code, so lets say you want to connect to the db, you can do new thread, then db code, which would connect in the background, or push everything else to the background, while you connect and work with the DB.  I would look into concurrency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all great answers, but I decided to go with a subcommand approach, similar to the one adopted by git: `git checkout ...` `git pull ...`.

So in my case, I would have something similar to this:

```
java -jar MyApplication.jar server
java -jar MyApplication.jar db:seed
java -jar MyApplication.jar db:backup
```

A naive implementation would probably be like something along the following lines:

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        if ("server".equals(args[0]) {
            new ServerCommand(args).run();
        }

        if ("db:seed".equals(args[0]) {
            new DataSeedCommand(args).run();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

The framework [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html#gs-running) already supports this pattern out of the box with the notion of `Command`. They have a default command `server` and custom commands can be registered via hooks ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106508/how-to-register-add-a-command-in-dropwizard)).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not using executable jars in this case.  You are likely going to make your life and the life of people running your application easier by creating scripts for each thing you want to run at the command line.  It will achieve the same result and it's more transparent and flexible than using executable jars.  Often when I encounter an executable jar, I will open it up, grab the main-class out of the manifest and build a script.  I would only use the executable jar option in very simple cases.

If you are hell-bent on using the executable jars, you can create a manifest-only jars that point to the jar that has all the classes in it to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real standard. I think the pattern you're suggesting works very well. You have one related codebase and deliverable to manage. At the moment I'm doing something similar in which a webserivce spawns off a Java process. I simply deliver the *one* jar file, and when running as a webservice, the forked process is simply invoking Java with the *same* classpath/jar file but a different entry point.

To make life easier, you could provide alongside your .jar file a shell script that takes arguments and determines which main class/method to call. So your clients don't have to worry about which package/class to invoke and you can refactor without exposing this to your clients.

Looking more at your particular requirements, however, is your web service managing your database, and as such, is it going to cause confusion to have separate executables amend your database directly ? If so, you may want to extend your webservice to provide these maintenance functions, and simply invoke on your webservice via a simple shell/curl/wget script.

Answer (score 1):

Imho there is no *standard* for this.

- Jetty uses the `web.xml` to find the asked servlet.
- Your JAR can contain multiple classes with a main-function in each.

In the MANIFEST of the JAR **one** class is set as default and will be started by `java -jar myprog.jar`. Any other main class can be started by `java -cp myprog.jar my.package.Scheduler`.

May be your interested in [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to create a *real* commandline interface.